# I'd like to solve django webserver collectstatic error in ubuntu server

Tags: python-3.x, django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn

I try to get static file to using 'python manage.py collectstatic', but it's not working.
I run my django project in `Ubuntu 20.04.4`, and using `Nginx` as a webserver, and `Guicorn` for WSGI server.

Here is my error log,

```
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings.

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/devadmin/venvs/bio_platform/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/devadmin/venvs/bio_platform/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/devadmin/venvs/bio_platform/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 414, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/devadmin/venvs/bio_platform/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 460, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/devadmin/venvs/bio_platform/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 209, in handle
    collected = self.collect()
  File "/home/devadmin/venvs/bio_platform/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 135, in collect
    handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
  File "/home/devadmin/venvs/bio_platform/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 368, in copy_file
    if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
  File "/home/devadmin/venvs/bio_platform/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 278, in delete_file
    if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
  File "/home/devadmin/venvs/bio_platform/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 362, in exists
    return os.path.lexists(self.path(name))
  File "/home/devadmin/venvs/bio_platform/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 39, in path
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
```

I found the many solution from google, and i guessing that it cause because i didn't set a `STATIC_ROOT` properly.

Here is my project dir structure and code below;

```
└── bio_platform
    ├── common
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── apps.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── apps.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── apps.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── forms.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── forms.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── forms.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── views.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── views.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views.py
    ├── config
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── wsgi.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── wsgi.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-39.pyc
    │   ├── asgi.py
    │   ├── settings
    │   │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── base.py
    │   │   ├── local.py
    │   │   └── prod.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    ├── node_modules
    │   └── bootstrap
    │       ├── LICENSE
    │       ├── README.md
    │       ├── dist
    │       ├── js
    │       ├── package.json
    │       └── scss
    ├── package-lock.json
    ├── pybo
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── apps.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── apps.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── apps.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── forms.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── forms.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── forms.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-310.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-38.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-39.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-310.pyc
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── forms.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   │   ├── 0002_question_author.py
    │   │   ├── 0003_answer_author.py
    │   │   ├── 0004_answer_modify_date_question_modify_date.py
    │   │   ├── 0005_comment.py
    │   │   ├── 0006_answer_voter_question_voter_alter_answer_author_and_more.py
    │   │   ├── 0007_auto_20220411_1325.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── templatetags
    │   │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   └── pybo_filter.py
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── views
    │       ├── __pycache__
    │       ├── answer_views.py
    │       ├── base_views.py
    │       ├── comment_views.py
    │       ├── question_views.py
    │       └── vote_views.py
    ├── static
    │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
    │   ├── bootstrap.min.js
    │   ├── jquery-3.6.0.min.js
    │   └── style.css
    ├── templates
    │   ├── base.html
    │   ├── common
    │   │   ├── login.html
    │   │   └── signup.html
    │   ├── form_errors.html
    │   ├── navbar.html
    │   └── pybo
    │       ├── answer_form.html
    │       ├── comment_form.html
    │       ├── question_detail.html
    │       ├── question_form.html
    │       └── question_list.html
    └── winehq.key
```

As you could notice, i divide my setting files like this,
It because i'd like to operate **Server development environment** and **Local development environment** separately.

```
├── settings
    │   │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── base.py
    │   │   ├── local.py
    │   │   └── prod.py
```

And here is my full code of setting files
(I blanked the private parts which is like IP address).

**base.py**

```
"""
Django settings for config project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'blank' #private part

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['blank'] #private part


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'common.apps.CommonConfig',
    'pybo.apps.PyboConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ko-kr'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Seoul'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [    
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
    ]

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

**local.py**

```
from .base import *

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

**prod.py**

```
from .base import *
import os

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['blank'] #private part
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
#STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
# concept addon
```

Also, here is my `bio_platform.service` for nignx server.

**bio_platform.service**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blank; #private part

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static {
        alias /home/devadmin/projects/bio_platform/static;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}
```

I did some of solution that given in google and stackoverflow also which is like:

**what i try**

> set a STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL on prod.py
> set a STATIC_ROOT and STATIC_URL on base.py

But as you know, it didn't work and `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.` error is still remain.

For know, i'm not sure where sould i set `STATIC_ROOT` or `STATIC_URL`, `STATICFILES_DIR`.
Please helpe me guys....

Comment: You can specify settings file by using `--settings` option or env variable. [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/settings/#the-django-admin-utility)

Comment: @LeeJeonghyun Thanks to your comment, i found which did i wrong. I was set the bio_platform.sh file to automaticly activate the django server into prod.py settings. But in that files code, i typed the path in worng way. Ty!

Answer (score 0):

I did found what i wrong in my project.
The problem was caused by path setting which is bring prod.py settings automaticly from venvs folder.

I made a bio_platform.sh file under the path
 `~/venvs/`

**before**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/projects/bio_paltform
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.prod
. ~/venvs/bio_paltform/bin/activate
```

As you guys could see that i typed wrong that `bio_paltform`.

So i change the `bio_paltform` to `bio_platform`.

**after**

```
#!/bin/bash

cd ~/projects/bio_platform
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=config.settings.prod
. ~/venvs/bio_platform/bin/activate
```

After i modify this file, `python managy.py collectstatic` order is work.

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic

You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /home/devadmin/projects/bio_platform/static

This will overwrite existing files!
Are you sure you want to do this?

Type 'yes' to continue, or 'no' to cancel: yes

128 static files copied to '/home/devadmin/projects/bio_platform/static'.
```